# $_POST data to phpExcel

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, phpexcel

I am trying to export data from a html table to an excel file using phpExcel. The issue I am having is that I cannot seem to get the data through to it.

I have the following jquery code which runs on a button press to get the data out of the table and post it to the php code.

export data jquery

```
function storeTblValues()
{
var tableData = new Array();

$('#LogsTable tr').each(function(row, tr) 
{
    if(row == 0) //Table Headers
    {
        tableData[row] = 
        {            
            "LogDate" : $(tr).find('th:eq(0)').text(),
            "LogType" : $(tr).find('th:eq(1)').text(),
            "StartTime" : $(tr).find('th:eq(2)').text(),
            "FinishTime" : $(tr).find('th:eq(3)').text(),
            "Duration" : $(tr).find('th:eq(4)').text()
        } 
    }
    else //Table data
    {
        tableData[row] = 
        {  
        "LogDate" : $(tr).find('td:eq(0)').text(),
        "LogType" : $(tr).find('td:eq(1)').text(),
        "StartTime" : $(tr).find('td:eq(2)').text(),
        "FinishTime" : $(tr).find('td:eq(3)').text(),
        "Duration" : $(tr).find('td:eq(4)').text(),
        }            
    }
});
return tableData;
}

function exportToExcel()
{      
    var tableData;        
    tableData = $.toJSON(storeTblValues());
    var tmp = "pTableData=" + tableData;   

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'create_export_files.php',
        data : tmp,    
        success : function(data)
        {
            window.location = 'create_export_files.php';        
        }
    });    
}
```

Top bit of the php file receiving the data
Create_export_files.php

```
$tableData = "";

if (isset($_POST["pTableData"]))
{
    $tableData = $_POST["pTableData"];
    $tableData = json_decode($tableData, TRUE);
}
else 
{
    $tableData = "empty";
}


generateExcel($tableData);

function generateExcel($tableData)
{

    /** Include PHPExcel */
    require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/../Classes/PHPExcel.php';
    // Create new PHPExcel object
    $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
        // Add some data
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
            ->setCellValue('A1', 'hello')
            ->setCellValue('B2', 'world!')
            ->setCellValue('C1', 'Hello')
            ->setCellValue('D2', 'world!');

// Rename worksheet
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Simple');


// Set active sheet index to the first sheet, so Excel opens this as the    first sheet
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
$filename = 'export '.date('d-m-Y h:i:a').'.xlsx';


// Redirect output to a client’s web browser (Excel2007)
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="'.$filename.'"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
// If you're serving to IE 9, then the following may be needed
header('Cache-Control: max-age=1');

// If you're serving to IE over SSL, then the following may be needed
header ('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT'); // Date in the past
header ('Last-Modified: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s').' GMT'); // always modified
header ('Cache-Control: cache, must-revalidate'); // HTTP/1.1
header ('Pragma: public'); // HTTP/1.0

$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
$objWriter->save('php://output');
}
```

I always seem to be going into the else part of the statement. Where am I going wrong?

If I remove the isset bit around the pTableData then the file gets created but is corrupted. Opening it in notepad++ I can see it says pTableData is undefined. Is that because the php file gets run again to make the file download?

Comment: The best way is export table to html(table.html), then change the table.html to table.xls.

Comment: Does that work for xlsx as well?

Comment: @ Al W yes, you can use this way create doc*,xls* files.

Comment: @phper - Except what you're suggesting doesn't actually create a document in native xls, xlsx, doc, etc format.... just a file that contains html markup with the extension you specify, and modern versions of MS Excel/Word/etc will tell you that the format isn't correct fornthe file in no uncertain terms..... highly unprofessional looking, and certainly not the ___best___ way

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
<?php
$str = "<table>
   <tr><td>a</td><td>b</td></tr>
   <tr><td>a</td><td>b</td></tr>
   <tr><td>a</td><td>b</td></tr>
   <tr><td>a</td><td>b</td></tr>
</table>
";
 file_put_contents("table.xls",$str);
```

Comment: I need the user to have the option of saving the file via the browser rather than just saving to a set location. In the php file I omitted the code where I am using phpExcel to do just that